# Why can I not declare this matrix?

Tags: c++, matrix, initializer-list

I am attempting to build a Tic Tac Toe game in C++, however, I am very beginner in C++ but can code reasonably confidently in Python.
This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char matrix[3][3] = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
void Draw()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
int main()
{   
    Draw();
    return 0;
}
```

There is a problem when the programme gets to the 4th item in the list at line 3.
E0146 - too many initializer values
C2078 - too many initializers
As such, the programme obviously won't run. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have googled around and not been able to find an answer.
Thanks

Have tried:
char *matrix[3][3] etc:
matrix[3][3] etc:

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so I didn't know that there was a difference between " " and ' '. This has solved the problem in case anyone else runs into something like this.

Comment: 'x' is a single character, that gets stored in a `char` variable. "x" is a character string of two bytes "x\0" (note the null character terminator) that needs a `char[2]` or a `char *`